# (CodeIgniter query builder) I'm getting a database insert error even though the insertion process works fine in the background

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
public function answerSurvey() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $i = 0;        
    $reserved = $this->mAttendee->getReserve($id, $this->session->username);
    $zxc = $reserved->registration_id;
    foreach ($_POST as $sample) {
        $value = $this->input->post("question_$i");
        $question = $this->input->post("id_$i");
        $qwe = array('answer_value' => $value, 'question_id' => $question, 'user_id' => $id);
        $this->MSurvey->addAnswer($qwe,$zxc);
        $i++;
    }
    redirect(base_url() . "attendee/viewEvent/$id");
```

Above is the snippet in my controller where I pass data from my looped post values into the database. When I run this method, I get a database error that says something along the lines like

> 'answer_value' and 'question_i' cannot be null

even though as you can see I passed data onto these values through the $value and $question variables. When I checked the database, the process of insertion seems to be working fine as my data is passed onto the tables. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it? My current solution was disabling the debugging in the database config. Thank you.

Comment: But do you pass values? You never check to see if `$this->input->post("question_$i");`  returns a value other than NULL - which it might. What do you do if it does not?

Comment: @DFriend it does. As I've said, the process of insertion is working fine in the background. The value echoes/displays properly when called.

Comment: Why do you put insert in a loop, and also the variable $sample is not used?

Comment: You would not get the error unless you are passing null values to the database. I suggest you look carefully at $_POST as it likely contains items that are not related to your insert. Your foreach loop will run once for each item in the $_POST array. Everything inserts just fine until the loop counter increments and the `$i` in "question_$i" creates an index that does not exist, at which point `input->post()` will return NULL. Don't forget, the submit button which is an input too and so is in the $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have much more elements in array *$_POST* than you expected in your loop eg. for array

```
array(
    'question_0' => 'a',
    'question_1' => 'b',
    'id_0' => '1',
    'id_1' => '2',
);
```

Your loop will iterate 4 times so for third and fourth iteration it will generate errors because items like *question_3*, *question_4* etc. does not exists in *$_POST* so *$this->input->post("id_$i")* returns *NULL*.